# Strong and weak chromatic number of infinite hypergraphs of finite rank

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph

Let $H = (V, E)$ be a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) such that every member of $E$ has more than $1$ element. Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal. We say that $c: V\to \kappa$ is a *weak coloring* if for all $e \in E$ the restriction $c|_e$ is not constant. We call $c$ a *strong coloring*, if for all $e \in E$ the restriction $c|_e$ is injective. We let $\chi_w(H)$ be the smallest cardinal such that there is a weak coloring to that cardinal, and we define $\chi_s(H)$ similarly for strong colorings.

Suppose all $e\in E$ have finitely many elements. (I.e., $H$ has *finite rank*<sup>(*)</sup>.) We do not require that $H$ be uniform. Is it possible that $\chi_w(H) < \aleph_0$ but $\chi_s(H) \geq \aleph_0$?

${}$____________________________

<sup>(*)</sup> Cf. e.g. page 2 in [C. Berge, *Hypergraphs*, North Holland, 1989, ISBN 0 444 87489 5].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP did not require that the rank of the hypergraph be *bounded*, the **answer to the question is 'obviously yes'**. An example is any  hypergraph $H$ which is<sup>(*)</sup> the

> disjoint union of $\aleph_0$-many hyperedges of *increasing cardinality*.

Then $\chi_w(H)=2$ but $\chi_s(H)=\aleph_0$. This answers the question.

${}$________________________

<sup>(*)</sup>Formally,let $\{v_{i,j}\colon (i,j)\in\omega^2\}$ be a set of $\aleph_0$-many pairwise distinct indeterminates, and let $H:=(\omega,\{\{ v_{i,j}\mid\ j\in i \}\mid\  i\in\omega\})$.

Comment: That's right - I meant "bounded", and will ask this in a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my omission, here is the updated question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297065/strong-and-weak-chromatic-number-of-infinite-bounded-hypergraphs